# innerHTML switch case counter

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to change the content in a div according to a counter (which changes with a button click) but it's not working. I'm trying this on my html page, within script tags:

```
function calcDivContent() {
  switch(counter) {
    case 1:
      $('#divID').html('<br>text here<br>');
      break;
    case 2:
      $('#divID').html('<br>more text<br>');
      break;
    default:
      $('#divID').html('<br>text here<br>');
  }
}
```

Adding this function into the code actually prevents me from clicking the button that changes the counter. I've also tried the format:

```
document.getElementById("divID").innerHTML='<br>text here<br>';
```

with the same outcome. It prevents my button from working, and no change of div content. I should mention that I don't think Sublime Text is recognizing .innerHTML as a method because it isn't changing the color to light blue like it is all other methods in my code.

Comment: How do you attach the event?

Comment: Please make a fiddle (and is the `<br>` supposed to be a break tag? If so, use `<br />` instead

Comment: is `counter` a global variable? you are not passing it into the function as a parameter

Comment: `<br>` is valid HTML5. `<br />` is legacy XHTML.

Comment: Also your switch statement should have a `break;` clause after every `case` otherwise all of the statements will run one after the other.

Comment: @MarkWalters you don't have to pass a variable into a javascript function, the scope allows that

Comment: @RUJordan What scope? Without knowing where the `counter` variable has come from how could you possible tell whether it was in scope or not from that snippet of code?

Comment: oops. i have break; in my code, just forgot to type it here. also the counter is scoped correctly, as it works for another switch function I have on the page. also I put switch(counter) { in my code and it doesn't work. I'll try to create a fiddle for this

Comment: @KevinBanas Try and create the fiddle. We need to see more of your code to know what is causing the issue. Are you getting any errors? have you tried adding alerts to see where the code is being executed til?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/u5H8x/

As mentioned by @alex attaching events is important

```
oCount.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    nCount += 1;
    switch(nCount) {
        case 1:
            oResult.innerHTML = 'One';
            break;
        case 2:
            oResult.innerHTML = 'Two';
            break;
        default:
            oResult.innerHTML = 'More than 2';
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you're missing an opening `{` from your `switch` statement. Try `switch(counter){` instead of `switch(counter)` and see if that helps.